# Is there an easy way to log additional exception properties with standard .net core ILogger interface?

Tags: logging, .net-core, console

This is valid for any custom exception, but in my case I use `Refit` library to connect to a 3d party API.

What happens is that I get a 401 Unauthorized exception in Refit in the form of `ApiException` and that's what is visible in Developer Exception Page and Console logging.

Problem is that it is really additional property of the exception i.e. `Content` in case of Refit that gives you a clue as of why this has happened.

So I am wondering if it's possible to configure logging/Developer Exception Page to dump out all custom properties of an Exception without writing some custom code for it.

I use standard `ILogger` to log exception:

```
_logger.LogError(e, "An unknown error has happened");
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just extend what you're writing there?

```
_logger.LogError(e, $"An unknown error has happened: {e.Message}");
```

Or am I missing the point?

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but imagine there are multiple different types of exceptions all with their own properties, so I would like just to "dump" them all. I can probably use JsonSerialize though to do it myself

Comment: I understand.. If you’re using Net Core on the web, I would have suggested custom middleware to handle it.. But by the tags it looks like you’re using Console? .. Another option, if your exceptions are not like to change could be extension methods on the ILogger? You can do custom formatting in each of those extensions then

Comment: Thanks for you help, I was really looking for out of the box solution that will dump the whole exception via ILogger. I am using asp.net, but it's run as the console app on linux.